# Background Image doesn't load over HTTPS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, http, https

Can anyone tell me how can i fixed this warning that chrome gives me?

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://support.desk.com/system/site_not_found'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

In my css,
the image is on file based

```
background-image: url("../../../images/checkers.jpg");
```

when i changed it to

```
background-image: url("https://example.com/images/checkers.jpg");
```

Nothing happens.
Please see image below:[image: 1]]

Comment: Please read the error message carefully. `http://support.desk.com/system/site_not_found` is pretty different from `https://example.com/images/checkers.jpg`.

Comment: Yeah, its kinda weird i'm having this error. I cannot find the `http://support.desk.com/system/site_not_found` everywhere

Comment: Take a look on this screenshot of the warning: https://imgur.com/IoPpHWi
I even check the `perpect-scrollbar.js` but there is no link same from error.

Comment: That's very important information you don't even mention. Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59573742/edit) and include: 1) The full error message (as text, please) 2) Details about the scrollbar plugin that's triggering it.

Comment: Either (a) the error message is talking about a different bit of code or (b) The URL is redirecting to an error page because the URL is just wrong in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Thats due to mixed content check why it is happening and how to resolve here:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

And if the image file size is small then there is another hack, convert your image to
base 64, it will give you simple text, use it as source of the image

To convert to base64 you can use this site: https://www.base64-image.de/

Then use background-image: url("PasteCompleteBase64TextHere");

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass image in http url bcz your project was run on http url.

For that,
Check that the URL is available over HTTP by opening a new tab in your browser, entering the URL in the address bar, and changing https:// to http://.
If the resource displayed is the same over HTTPS and HTTP, everything is OK.

For more details check this site:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content